# How to rename mutliples files in r

Tags: r, loops, rename

I need to convert over 100 images name into a format like: SITE_T001_L001.jpg, where Site is CGS1, T= TUBES, L= image number.

All those images are contain into a single file named CGS1 (the site), subdivided by file named accordingly to their tubes number. Then the images are organised by date. This order represents the image number. The first one is 1, the second one is two.(the alpahabetic order is not correct)

here, I have a graphical representation: 
[image]
I found how to do it manually in R

```
file.rename("Snap_029.jpg",
        paste("CGS1","T001","L003", ".jpg", sep = "_"))
```

but is there anyway to automate it with a loop?

In more details - as requested in the response:
I have this series of input filenames (including leading path)- ordered by dates of modification (important).

```
file_list
[1] "CGS1/1/Snap_001.jpg" "CGS1/1/Snap_002.jpg" "CGS1/1/Snap_005.jpg" "CGS1/2/Snap_006.jpg" "CGS1/2/Snap_007.jpg" "CGS1/2/Snap_082.jpg"
```

I am looking to modify the name of each images following the main folder CGS1, the subfolder from T001 to T002, and following the date of modification from L001 to L003 as this output filenames

```
new_file_list
 [1] "CGS1_T001_L001.jpg" "CGS1_T001_L002.jpg" "CGS1_T001_L003.jpg" "CGS1_T002_L001.jpg" "CGS1_T002_L002.jpg" "CGS1_T002_L003.jpg"
```

Comment: Try `cd`ing into the directory that holds the files, `list.files` and `*apply`/`map*` over that and add the `file.rename` inside that.

Comment: Thanks Nelson. it seems interesting but I have troubles to follow you. can you give me  more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```r
file_list <- list.files(path = "...", recursive = TRUE, pattern = "\\.jpg$")
### for testing
file_list <- c(
  "CGS1/1/Snap_001.jpg", "CGS1/1/Snap_005.jpg", "CGS1/1/Snap_002.jpg",
  "CGS1/2/Snap_006.jpg", "CGS1/2/Snap_007.jpg", "CGS1/2/Snap_0082.jpg"
)

spl <- strsplit(file_list, "[/\\\\]")
# ensure that all files are exactly two levels down
stopifnot(all(lengths(spl) == 3))

m <- do.call(rbind, spl)
m
#      [,1]   [,2] [,3]           
# [1,] "CGS1" "1"  "Snap_001.jpg" 
# [2,] "CGS1" "1"  "Snap_005.jpg" 
# [3,] "CGS1" "1"  "Snap_002.jpg" 
# [4,] "CGS1" "2"  "Snap_006.jpg" 
# [5,] "CGS1" "2"  "Snap_007.jpg" 
# [6,] "CGS1" "2"  "Snap_0082.jpg"
```

From this, we'll update the second/third columns to be what you expect.

```r
# either one (not both), depending on if you are guaranteed integers
m[,2] <- sprintf("T%03.0f", as.integer(m[,2]))
# ... or if you may have non-numbers
m[,2] <- paste0("T", strrep("0", max(0, 3 - nchar(m[,2]))), m[,2])

# since we really don't care about 'Snap_001.jpg' (etc), we can discard the third column
new_file_list <- apply(m[,1:2], 1, paste, collapse = "_")
# back-street way of applying sequences to each CGS/T combination while preserving order
for (prefix in unique(new_file_list)) {
  new_file_list[new_file_list == prefix] <- sprintf("%s_L%03d.jpg",
                                                    new_file_list[new_file_list == prefix],
                                                    seq_len(sum(new_file_list == prefix)))
}
new_file_list
# [1] "CGS1_T001_L001.jpg" "CGS1_T001_L002.jpg" "CGS1_T001_L003.jpg"
# [4] "CGS1_T002_L001.jpg" "CGS1_T002_L002.jpg" "CGS1_T002_L003.jpg"
```

Now it's a matter of renaming. Note that this will *move* all files into the current directory.

```r
file.rename(file_list, new_file_list)
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!

Comment: All works perfectly, except to rename the file. It send FALSE. I did not manage to figure out why- anybody?

Comment: File permissions? File "busy"? Target-directory permissions? Target-file exists?

Comment: There is a small problem with the renaming of the image numbers. Is it possible to rename them taking into account the tube number? For example, in my example, we will have: CGS1_T001_L001.jpg,CGS1_T001_L002.jpg,CGS1_T001_L003.jpg, CGS1_T002_L001.jpg,CGS1_T002_L002.jpg, CGS1_T002_L003.jpg. In each of my tube file I have the exact same number of images.

Comment: I don't understand. Given the image you provided, there is no duplication of output filenames.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I am aiming to get the L from L001 to L0046 for each tube number (I have for each tube 46 images). For instance, taking the example that I posted in my initial question (see the image above). Snap_001.jpg will be CGS1_T001_L001.jpg, Snap_005.jpg will be CGS1_T001_L002.jpg, Snap_002.jpg -->CGS1_T001_L003.jpg, Snap_006.jpg-->CGS1_T002_L001.jpg, Snap_007.JPG-->CGS1_T002_L002.jpg, Snap_0082.jpg-->CGS1_T002_L003.jpg.Is that clearer?

Comment: Your image states *"order by dates"* and points from file `Snap_005.jpg` to `CGS1_T001_L002.jpg`, implying that the tube number (assuming `005` in that line) was to be ignored. Can you give a series of input filenames (including leading path) and output filenames in a fully reproducible manner instead of relying on inference from an image?

Comment: I edited the questions. My input file name is 
    `"CGS1/1/Snap_001.jpg" "CGS1/1/Snap_002.jpg" "CGS1/1/Snap_005.jpg" "CGS1/2/Snap_006.jpg" "CGS1/2/Snap_007.jpg" "CGS1/2/Snap_082.jpg"`

 my output file name is 
   `[1] "CGS1_T001_L001.jpg" "CGS1_T001_L002.jpg" "CGS1_T001_L003.jpg" "CGS1_T002_L001.jpg" "CGS1_T002_L002.jpg" "CGS1_T002_L003.jpg"` - You are right the order by date is correct, there is just another layer, it should be ordered by tubes and by dates of modification. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: See my edit, I think it does what you were asking for.

Comment: It works out! Just need to be carefull to have the file well ordered by time and not by name from the beginning! Thanks a lot - that is great :)

Comment: Right, sorry, that part slipped out ... right after defining `file_list`, you can do `file_list <- file_list[ order(file.info(file_list)$mtime) ]` to sort them by-date, which will then be preserved in the post-numbering later on.